# How to deal with bad attitude/manners

Tags: discussion

This guy posted a question, I answered it with the good answer.

He reposted my answer as his own answer to his OWN POST and didn't even talk to me or anything.

[FileReader not working in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232477/filereader-not-working-in-angular-2/50233248#50233248)

Comment: There's significant differences between your answer and his, though, including in the code. Are you really sure he stole your answer?

Comment: Some lines match between the answers, but not all of it. This doesn't qualify as "Plagiarism".

Comment: If you truly believe someone plagiarised your answer (copied it without noting you as the author), the appropriate course would be to flag the post for moderator attention, and describe what happened. However, as the previous comments noted, that isn't clear, and your flag will likely get declined. While it's polite for askers to comment on an answer, noting if it did or didn't work, it's not required.

Comment: I have no problem about him including my answer in his but he didn't even said thanks or anything, I was helping him in the comment aswell but I deleted it because it was flooding.

Comment: @TheSegfault Saying "thanks" is not only not required, but discouraged. They probably upvoted your post, since you had an upvote before the answer was linked from meta. An upvote is the best possible "thank you".

Comment: He thanked god, I think he meant you.  Have an upvote to make you feel better.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify this a bad attiture/manners ... I don't see anything bad on posting answer to our question and who knows, maybe he upvoted you

Comment: Wait, you say he wasn't talking to you... but there was help in the comments?  In any case, he leveraged your answer to craft his own, more complete, more adapted to his usecase. It's not bad attitude at all.... (not to mention he may have upvoted you, which is the proper way to give "thanks")

Comment: And my answer is clearly the one he needed to get further, he just rearranged the code and posted it but still, I'm just asking for a "thanks"

Comment: @TheSegfault if he upvoted you, you got your thanks. You shouldn't be posting on Stack to get thanks from OPs anyway

Comment: He didn't upvoted me, I had my first upvote by posting in meta

Comment: @TheSegfault Again, "thank you" comments are not really welcome in SO. And you had an upvote before you posted here, so they (the question author) were probably the ones doing the upvoting.

Comment: _"He didn't upvoted me, I had my first upvote by posting in meta"_ Maybe that first upvote was from him?

Comment: Understood :) this is just discouraging to help, spend time and just having no consideration for the help gived

Comment: If they upvoted your post, why isn't that enough? Upvotes are very nice.

Comment: @Cerbrus Indeed, "Maybe" but when I posted I was at 0

Comment: You got 2 upvotes for an answer. That gave you 20 rep. How did you get no consideration? If you want the original poster to write you a thank you note for your answer... your expectations of the site don't match the way this community works, unfortunately :/

Comment: @Patrice Omg this escalade too quickly, Patrice, I had no upvote at all before posting on Meta Stack, I wouldn't otherwise, the consideration comes from you guys, not the poster

Comment: *the consideration comes from you guys, not the poster* Voting is anonymous, you can't prove that the OP didn't up vote your answer.

Comment: @TheSegfault a) as soon as I checked your question I saw an upvote, so we can agree to disagree here, as from my PoV I saw only an upvoted answer since you posted here. Timing or caching may indeed be at play and I can be wrong there. b) even if he didn't upvote your answer... you shouldn't answer with the assumption "The OP will personally thank me".

Comment: Just improve your answer if possible you will receive upvotes over time as it helps more searchers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not getting thanked for your answer is just something that happens on Stack Overflow.
It's not "rude", it's not a "bad attitude". It's a shame, at worst.

There's nothing you can do about this.

That said, "Thanks" *comments* are generally considered to be "noise", and usually removed, as they don't add value to the answer.

Comment: I agree I overkilled it

Comment: Hehe, the irony. No upvotes / accept mark ;-)

Comment: @TheSegfault It is actually stated in the comment box under an answer itself: _"Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"."_

Comment: @Cerbrus I hope you are insulted right now...

Comment: @Patrice: Extremely.

Comment: @Veljko89 Careful, you can't thanks people or André will flag you

Comment: @TheSegfault Nope, I'm doing exactly what I said: avoiding them!